# Which component in nativescript UI canbe used as the replacement of Kendo panelbar

Tags: html, angular, typescript, nativescript

If Native script doesnot provide panelbar which component can be used as close as panelbar in Nativescript.

Comment: Welcome! Please include additional information. What components have you looked at already? Links to documentation.

Comment: Generally you have ActionBar for each page in your mobile app, you may add action items to it.